# Error reading S3 Object in Step Function "Failed to convert 'Body' to string"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Function that resumes a Redshift cluster, then retrieves a script from S3 to run.

However, the step that retrieves the script from S3 returns in this error:

> S3.InvalidContent in step: Get Script From S3 "Failed to convert 'Body' to string"

The parameters for the step are as follows:

```
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Next": "Batch Execute Script",
  "Parameters": {
    "Bucket": "<bucketname>",
    "Key": "<keypath>"
  },
  "ResultSelector": {
    "Statements.$": "States.StringToJson($.Body)"
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:getObject"
}
```

The file is JSON stored as text; it contains an array of scripts to pass to BatchExecute, but the same error is encountered if ResultSelector is omitted. Could only find two references to this error, one user trying to load a .wav file and another saying he fixed it by setting the parameters in the execution parameters, which I can't feasibly do due to how far down this step is.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was something subtle but obvious in hindsight. I had generated the file by taking a large script and splitting it in PowerShell, then converting it to JSON and writing to file.

PowerShell's `Out-File` defaults to UTF-16 which seems to be incompatible with GetObject. Specifying UTF-8 encoding has resolved the error.

Comment: Just wondering why you did not use code and the JavaScript SDK to build the AWS Lambda functions used in the AWS Step Functions workflow.